# How do I get the parent NotesViewEntry from the NotesXSPViewEntry?

Tags: javascript, view, xpages

Using SSJS I have a handle to a NotesXSPViewEntry which is a category in view,now I need to get the parent category from that entry as a NotesViewEntry, so I tried to use NotesXSPViewEntry.getParent() but that returns a notesViewNavigator instead of a NotesViewEntry.

How do I get the parent NotesViewEntry from the notesXSPViewEntry? or how do I convert a notesXSPViewEntry to a NotesViewEntry?

Comment: How do you get that handle? Is it possible to get parent entry in advance?

Answer (score 1):

One solution: get the position with `getNavigatorPosition()`. The get the NotesViewNavigator with getParent(), call `gotoPos()` with that position as parameter, then `getPrev()` should return the previous entry and `getParent()` the parent entry.

You might be able to leave the gotoPos() call out: `getParent().getCurrent().getParent()` should return XSPViewEntry's navigator's current entry's parent entry.

Comment: Just be cautious... if you're calling this from inside a view panel / repeat / data view, etc. (basically, any component that is iterating a view index on your behalf), by calling methods against the navigator, you may inadvertently reset the cursor, which could cause view entries to be skipped during rendering -- or worse, an infinite loop, because in a child you're resetting the cursor to a parent, which then navigates to a child, which resets to the parent, which navigates to a child.......