# Using ODA's isBefore and isAfter methods for date comparisons

Tags: xpages

in an XPage repeat control I'm trying to compute a string based upon date values in the underlying Notes view. The first two columns of the view are StartDate and EndDate respectively.

In my code (see below) the print statements work fine and prints lovely looking dates on the console. As soon as it gets to the date comparisons it throws some horrible errors.

```
var vReturn = "unknown";
try {
    var vNow = new java.util.Date();
    var vDateToday:org.openntf.domino.DateTime = session.createDateTime(vNow);
    print("Today=" + vDateToday);
    var vStartDate:org.openntf.domino.DateTime = row.getColumnValues()[0];
    print("vStartDate=" + vStartDate);
    var vEndDate:org.openntf.domino.DateTime = row.getColumnValues()[1];
    print("vEndDate=" + vEndDate);

    if (vDateToday.isBefore(vStartDate)) {
        vReturn = "Forthcoming";
    }
    if (vDateToday.isAfter(vStartDate) && vDateToday.isBefore(vEndDate)) {
        vReturn = "Current";
    }
    if (vDateToday.isAfter(vEndDate)) {
        vReturn = "Completed";
    }

}catch(e){
    print("Travellog: " + e.toString());
}
return vReturn;
```

The first dozen or so lines output to the console looks like this:

```
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM: Today=19/12/2016 11:25:45 GMT
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM: vStartDate=19/12/2016 00:00:00 GMT
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM: vEndDate=27/12/2016 00:00:00 GMT
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM: java.lang.NullPointerException
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.xsp.script.WrapperOpenDomino$OpenFunction.call(WrapperOpenDomino.java:400)
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.types.BuiltinFunction.call(BuiltinFunction.java:75)
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:79)
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109)
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
19/12/2016 11:25:45   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
...
```

I have tried wrapping getColumnValues in session.CreateDateTime like so:

```
var vStartDate:org.openntf.domino.DateTime = session.createDateTime(row.getColumnValues()[0])
```

but that throws errors too.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've tried every variation I can think of!

P.S. The examples in the OpenNTF Domino example database look simple but they only ever use the current system date, never dates from documents or view entries.

Comment: Have you got `org.openntf.domino.xsp=godmode` enabled in the application? Also, it's worth outputting `.getClass().getName()` on the result of the `getColumnValues()`.

Comment: Yes, I have godmode enabled. I added a couple of print statements to output `.getClass().getName()` and both columns return `lotus.domino.localDateTime`

Comment: What about `row`? Is that a `NotesViewEntry` or a `NotesXspViewEntry`? You may need to get the backend `NotesViewEntry` to get the column as an `org.openntf.domino.DateTime`. That's the one we've extended, not `NotesXspViewEntry`.

Comment: It's `NotesXspViewEntry` as I found out. My code is executing inside a repeat control. "row" is the name of the variable representing each view entry. Until today I didn't know that repeat controls iterate over the view index in the same was as a navigator. Lesson learned. I've posted a full answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul's comment where he points out that there is a difference between `NotesViewEntry` and `NotesXspViewEntry` pointed me in the right direction. My code is in a repeat control and it turns out that repeat controls return NotesXspViewEntries. I messed about trying to get the underlying NotesViewEntry but after reading a comment by Tim Tripconey about the dangers of doing this (see [How do I get the parent NotesViewEntry from the NotesXSPViewEntry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376018/how-do-i-get-the-parent-notesviewentry-from-the-notesxspviewentry)) I decided to go for the underlying document instead. Here is my code:

```
var vReturn = "unknown";
try {
    var vNow = new java.util.Date();
    var vDateToday:org.openntf.domino.DateTime = session.createDateTime(vNow);
    var vDoc:NotesDocument = row.getDocument();
    var vStartDate:org.openntf.domino.DateTime = vDoc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("DateStart").get(0);
    var vEndDate:org.openntf.domino.DateTime = vDoc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("DateEnd").get(0);

    if (vDateToday.isBeforeIgnoreTime(vStartDate)) {
        vReturn = "Forthcoming";
    }
    if ((vDateToday.equalsIgnoreTime(vStartDate) || vDateToday.isAfterIgnoreTime(vStartDate))
         && (vDateToday.equalsIgnoreTime(vEndDate) || vDateToday.isBefore(vEndDate))) {
        vReturn = "Currently Away";
    }
    if (vDateToday.isAfterIgnoreTime(vEndDate)) {
        vReturn = "Completed";
    }

}catch(e){
    print("Travellog: error in itinerary status link on home page: " + e.toString());
}
return vReturn;
```

I probably need to make it a bit more robust - e.g. if one of the date fields does not contain a value (because a date field with no value returns an empty string which causes `.getItemValueDateTimeArray` to throw an error).

Thanks for your help Paul. Once again you've pulled me out of the coding bottomless pit!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your columns aren't displaying dates. The following button code in that demo database works successfully for me:

```
<xp:button value="Run SSJS Tests" id="button4"
                    xp:key="SSJSButton">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="SSJSDiv">
                        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
var now = new java.util.Date();
var vw:NotesView = database.getView("AllContacts");
var ec:NotesViewEntryCollection = vw.getAllEntries();
var ent1 = ec.getFirstEntry();
var ent2 = ec.getNextEntry();
print(ent1.getColumnValues());
print(ent1.getColumnValues().get(6).getClass().getName());
var date1:org.openntf.domino.DateTime = ent1.getColumnValues().get(6);
var date2:org.openntf.domino.DateTime = ent2.getColumnValues().get(6);
date1.adjustDay(1);
retVal = "Running SSJS date1.isAfter(date2)<br/>";
if (date1.isAfter(date2)) {
    retVal += @Text(date1) + " is after " + @Text(date2) + "<br/>";
} else {
    retVal += @Text(date1) + " is NOT after " + @Text(date2) + "<br/>";
}
retVal += "<br/><br/>Running SSJS date2.isAfter(date1)<br/>";
if (date2.isAfter(date1)) {
    retVal += @Text(date2) + " is after " + @Text(date1) + "<br/>";
} else {
    retVal += @Text(date2) + " is NOT after " + @Text(date1) + "<br/>";
}
viewScope.put("SSJSTest",retVal);
} catch (e) {
    @ErrorMessage(e.toString());
}}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:button>
```

Possibly a better option is to use `row.setPreferJavaDates()`. That then ensures a Java Date (`java.util.Date`) is outputted instead of a `NotesDateTime`. That also removes the need to recycle. The `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` methods just convert the `NotesDateTime` to a `java.util.Date` and use the in-built `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` methods available in that class anyway.